# Finiding common lines for two files using bash

Tags: bash, sorting, grep, comm

I am trying to compare two files and output a file which consists of common names for both.

File1

```
1990.A.BHT.s_fil 4.70 
1991.H.BHT.s_fil 2.34 
1992.O.BHT.s_fil 3.67 
1993.C.BHT.s_fil -1.50
1994.I.BHT.s_fil -3.29 
1995.K.BHT.s_fil -4.01
```

File2

```
1990.A.BHT_ScS.dat 1537  -2.21
1993.C.BHT_ScS.dat 1494  1.13
1994.I.BHT_ScS.dat 1545  0.15
1995.K.BHT_ScS.dat 1624  1.15
```

I want to compare the first parts of the names ** (ex:1990.A.BHT ) **  on both files and output a file which has common names with the values on 2nd column in file1 to file3

ex: file3 (output)

```
1990.A.BHT.s_fil 4.70 
1993.C.BHT.s_fil -1.50
1994.I.BHT.s_fil -3.29
1995.K.BHT.s_fil -4.01
```

I used following codes which uses grep command

```
while read line 
do
grep $line file1 >> file3
done < file2
```

and

```
grep -wf file1 file2 > file3
```

I sort the files before using this script.
But I get an empty `file3`. Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: None of the lines in the two files match. `file1` has 2 columns, `file2` has 3 columns. And the first column in file1 ends with `.s_fil` while the corresponding names in file2 end with `.dat`.

Comment: Do you just want to compare the names without those suffixes? None of the code you've written removes the suffixes and just compares that field.

Comment: All the tools you've tried to use require exact matches of the lines, it doesn't seem like you've made any attempt to check just the part you care about.

Comment: @Barmar   Yes I want to compare names without the suffixes and output file1 values to file3

Comment: So what have you tried? The code you posted is clearly not an attempt to do that.

Comment: We'll help you fix problems in your code if you make an honest attempt, but we're not going to write it for you.

Comment: Hello @Barmar I've also tried grep -f file1 file2 > file3 which would search for patterns.

Comment: There are no patterns in `file1`. A regular expression pattern would be something like `^1990\.A\.BHT_ScS\..*`

Comment: Also I've changed the file1 using sed -i  's/.s_fil/_ScS.dat/g' file1.txt. and then compare the files. which is what works atm

Comment: You need to remove the rest of the line, otherwise it won't match because of the numbers at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove everything starting from `_SCS.dat` from the lines in `file2`. Then you can use that as a pattern to match lines in file1.

```
grep -F -f <(sed 's/_SCS\.dat.*//' file2) file1 > file3
```

The `-F` option matches fixed strings rather than treating them as regular expressions.

Comment: @Monika Accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score -1):

In your example data, the lines appear to be in sorted order. If you can guarantee that they always are, `comm -1 -2 file1 file2` would do the job. If they can be unsorted, do a

```
comm -1 -2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Comment: How can this possibly work when the lines don't actually match, only the beginning of the first fields match? This is the same mistake the OP made.